# Reverse for 'product_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/detail/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I was trying to make urls as human-readable urls with slug, instead of using the `pk` that Django automatically gives me. However, it keeps making me fail to include slug into my URL by throwing `NoReverseMatch`

Here are my codes that are relevant to my works.

#### models.py

```py
from django.urls import reverse 

class Product(TimeStampModel):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, null=False, default='', editable=False)
    
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.utils.text import slugify 
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.product_name, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        kwargs = {
            'slug': self.slug,
        }
        return reverse('products:product_detail', kwargs=kwargs)
```

#### views.py

- `ProductListView` is the view that shows products from all categories
- `ProductDetailView` is the view of detail page of product.

```py
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = models.Product
    template_name = 'products/product_all.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    paginate_by = 12
    paginate_orphans = 5
    ordering = 'created'

class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Product
    template_name = 'products/product_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
```

#### urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

app_name = 'products'

urlpatterns = [
    path('all/', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list_all'),
    paht('detail/<slug:slug>/', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
]
```

#### settings.py/urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('products/', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    ...
]
```

#### products/admin.py

I didn't do anything with admin.py with `SlugField`

#### templates

- Directory for template file for `ProductListView` is `templates/products/product_all.html`
- Directory for template file for `ProductDetailView` is `templates/products/product_detail.html`

```html
<section id="all" class="product-list">
    <ul class="item-grid">
        {% for product in products %}
        <li class="item">
            <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                <img src="{{ product.product_thumbnail.url }}" alt="product-image" class="product-image">
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h1 class="product-name">{{ product.product_name }}</h1>
                    <h2 class="product-price">{{ product.product_price }}</h2>
                </div>    
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</section>
```

## Which error did I got

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/all/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.9.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'common.apps.CommonConfig',
 'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
 'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
 'compressor',
 'django_countries']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/apensia914/dev/knowner-website/templates/base.html, error at line 14
   Reverse for 'product_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': '반팔티2'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/detail/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
   4 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   5 : <html lang="en">
   6 : <head>
   7 :     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   8 :     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   9 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   10 :     {% compress css %}
   11 :         <link type="text/x-scss" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'scss/base.scss' %}">
   12 :     {% block style %}{% endblock style %}
   13 :     {% endcompress %}
   14 :     <title>{% block title %}{% e ndblock title %} | Knowner</ti tle>
   15 : </head>
   16 : <body>
   17 :     {% include 'partials/header.html' %}
   18 :     
   19 :     {% block content %}
   20 :     {% endblock content %}
   21 : 
   22 :     {% include 'partials/footer.html' %}
   23 :     <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/00dde58123.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   24 : </body>


Traceback:

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  143.                 response = response.render()

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  987.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  671.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  796.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  858.                             current = current()

File "/Users/apensia914/dev/knowner-website/products/models.py" in get_absolute_url
  72.         return reverse('products:product_detail', kwargs=kwargs)

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "/Users/apensia914/.local/share/virtualenvs/knowner-website-tJGoHC0L/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  673.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /products/all/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'product_detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': '반팔티2'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['products/detail/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

I surely passed the `slug` value but it still  cannot catching. Are there any mistakes that I am making?

Comment: `self.slug = slugify(self.product_name, allow_unicode)` makes no sense, it should be `self.slug = slugify(self.product_name, allow_unicode=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
self.slug = slugify(self.product_name, allow_unicode)=True
```

makes no sense since you pass the value of `allow_unicode` as parameter, and you assign it to `True`. Likely you meant:

```
self.slug = slugify(self.product_name, allow_unicode=True)
```

Furthermore if an object is not saved, or the `.save()` is circumvented (for example by creating records in *bulk*, `slug` will be empty). You can try to fix this with:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    kwargs = {
        'slug': self.slug or slugify(self.product_name, allow_unicode=True),
    }
    return reverse('products:product_detail', kwargs=kwargs)
```

You should also ensure that `product_name` is not empty itself (likely by removing `blank=True`), and marking it as `unique=True`.

The `<slug:…>` at the moment only works with Roman characters, you thus will need to specify a slug field with:

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('all/', views.ProductListView.as_view(), name='product_list_all'),
    re_path('detail/(?<slug>[\w-])+/', views.ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
]
```

Comment: Firstly, my apology for type for `self.slug`. Closing parenthesis should be end of the code.

I included the `product_name` with unique name, but still it throws the same problem of `Reverse for 'product_detail' with keyword arguemtns {'slug': 'tshirts'} not found.`

Comment: @DonghoonHan: did you set an `app_name = ...` in the `urls.py`?

Comment: @William Yes I did. I named it as `app_name = 'products'`

Comment: What if you use `allow_unicode=False`? Note that the `allow_unicode=True`, can result in values that do *not* match the URL path converter for `slug`.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I even deleted `allow_unicode=True` for this. 
Do I need to include `slug` field viewable in admin model manually. Actually, I just wanted to be `product_name` can automatically can be `slug` either.

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the *full error* (and the *full* traceback)?

Comment: Yes I did. I also included settings.py's urls.py and admin.py too.

Comment: @DonghoonHan: you will need to specify the URL with `re_path` at the moment, since the `<slug:...>` url pattern only accepts slugs with *Roman* characters.

Comment: That worked! By the way, your saying "only accepts slugs with *Roman* characters" mean that my urlpatterns cannot accept hyphen(-) too?

Comment: @DonghoonHan: it accepts `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/urls/converters.py#L36

Comment: Quite weird tho.. I saw many blogs using only `<slug:slug>` in the url patterns and still works. Anyway, using `re_path` fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DonghoonHan: as long as you only slugify with `allow_unicode=False`, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Verify all objects have value in the slug field.
In my case I created slug field after data is inserted. So that I updated every objects from admin page. There I missed for some object to add value to slug field. When I added it worked for me