# What is the problem if str:slug is used in django urls?

Tags: django, url, slug

Hey guys I am building a website with django and I have to use slugs. Model and URL look like this

Model

```
slug = models.SlugField(null=False, allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
```

URL

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('selectlanguage', views.selectlanguage, name='selectlanguage'),
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path(_('product/<str:slug>/'), views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    prefix_default_language=False,
)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I used slug:slug in urls it doesn't let me change language between slugs it gives me "Reverse" error. But str:slug gives me no problem.

The error shown is this
Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(1, 'በ')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['am/product/(?P[0-9]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

My question is, is there any problem of using str:slug over slug:slug that can cause SEO or other problem to the website? I want to know if it causes any issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Firstly, `<str:slug>/` means string and `<slug:slug>/` means slug, string can also be like this `this_is_any-string`, but the slug should be `this-is-any-string`. Strings can also contain spaces.

Comment: Thank you @Sunderam Dubey. translation is giving me "Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(1, 'slug')' not found" error when I use <slug:slug>/. What should I do?

Comment: Can you share necessary view, model and the template? Also share full traceback of error.

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey I have added the full error. I think the problem is slug in url is comparing to ASCII letters or numbers only. Thats why it is not only working when translating

Comment: The issue can be because of several things, so not sure about this, as you haven't shared view logic and the respective template, but you can still refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68243625/17562044) answer, it might help you.